# Get Monolog JSON Stack Trace as Array

Tags: php, laravel, monolog

I'm using Laravel 4.2 and want to get logs out as JSON. Laravel uses Monolog, so I've configured the JSON formatter like so:

```
$logHandler = new Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler(Config::get('app.logFile'), Monolog\Logger::DEBUG);
$logHandler->setFormatter(new Monolog\Formatter\JsonFormatter);
Log::getMonolog()->pushHandler($logHandler);
```

The problem is that stack traces are included as part of the message string, like so:

```
{
    "message": "exception 'Exception' with message 'Socket operation failed: Host name lookup failure' in /var/www/vendor/clue/socket-raw/Socket/Raw/Socket.php:388\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/vendor/clue/socket-raw/So..."
}
```

Can someone point me in the right direction to make the stack trace its own separate array in the json?

Comment: Looks like this was added as a feature in a recent commit: https://github.com/phansys/monolog/blob/e8e1d9efa3df4ae5456bdb417d721a5a3e613c6b/src/Monolog/Formatter/JsonFormatter.php

Comment: Oh cool! I have since written my own JsonFormatter, which looks remarkably like what they've added. With Laravel in particular there's more involved, so sometime I'll post what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Long overdue update:

The primary problem is that Laravel, and lots of code following its example, tries to log the exception by itself, e.g., `Log::error($e)`. **This is the wrong way to log an exception with Monolog.** That first parameter is supposed to be a simple message string. In processing it, `Monolog\Logger::addRecord()` explicitly casts the message to a string:

```
$record = array(
    'message' => (string) $message,
    //...
);
```

If `$message` is actually an exception, you get the whole stack trace as a string. Unfortunately, this is what Laravel's [default exception handler does](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/fd307c028a6f58c4ae644d5d46a570f054bfd9e3/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php#L56).

The correct way to get a stack trace as an array is to pass the exception in as context so that it's available non-stringified to the formatter. For instance:

```
Log::error($e->getMessage(), ['exception' => $e]);
```

Something equivalent is what you need to put in your custom exception handler for Laravel, and then you can use a proper JSON formatter and get what you except.

Comment: Laravel now has this correct method of logging :D the source code: `$logger->error(
            $e->getMessage(),
            array_merge($this->context(), ['exception' => $e]
        ));`